# How to select a Start and End date in a Datepicker using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, datepicker

i have to generate a  report with a datepicker.
I use Selenium webdriver with Eclipse.

Firebug shows me a start date with xpath but when i execute with java, the xpath is never found. So i read some informations about the date picker but i'm not able to find the start date and end date.

for example the start date should be : 20/08/2014 and end date=31-08-2014
Can you help me, thank you.

Here is the html code for the date picker:

```
<div class="input-append date datepicker-start" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
            <input class="span2 start-date" type="text" value="2014-08-20" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" size="16" name="start"></input>
            <span class="add-on">
                <i class="enticon-calendar"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="control-group">

    <label class="control-label">

        End Date

    </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-append date datepicker-end" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-date="">
            <input class="span2 end-date" type="text" value="2014-08-31" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" size="16" name="end"></input>
            <span class="add-on">
                <i class="enticon-calendar"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

this example is not found i execute with java:

driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/div/..")).click();

Comment: It's on testing environment which is available only from my company.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use alternative CSS selector approach.
To resolve your issue try the following:

**1)[START DATE PICK ATTEMPT] try to click on the div element**

```
<div class="input-append date datepicker-start" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
```

=> click operation:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.input-append.date.datepicker-start")).click();
```

**2) [START DATE PICK ATTEMPT] try to click on the input following div above as a child:**

```
 <input class="span2 start-date" type="text" value="2014-08-20" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" size="16" name="start"></input>
```

=> click operation:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.span2.start-date")).click();
```

**3) [END DATE PICK ATTEMPT] clicking on the div**

```
<div class="input-append date datepicker-end" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" data-date="">
```

=> click operation:

```
 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.input-append.date.datepicker-end")).click();
```

**4) [END DATE PICK ATTEMPT]**
clicking on the input

```
 <input class="span2 end-date" type="text" value="2014-08-31" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" size="16" name="end"></input>

 driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.span2.end-date")).click();
```

try these ones alternative and tell whether they work you.

Comment: Hi, it's working when with driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.span2.end-date")).click(); and driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.span2.start-date")).click(); and i can choose the date like for start date and end date, if restart the test, it could not find the element for choosing the start date and end date as 20/08/2014 and 31-08-2014